# target build-dev does not exist in this project build-test.xml

Tags: ant, build

In my project there are set of ant files.
In one of a ant file it gives the above error.

In the build-test.xml file one ant target depends on the "build-dev" target,  which is available in build-dev.xml file in the same directory.

What is the problem of this?

in the build-dev.xml following target has been defined.

```
target name="build-dev" description="Compile the source code">
<echo>Building development classes ...</echo>
<foreach list="dev" param="type" target="build-core-type"/>
```

And in the build-test.xml file it is referred as follows

```
<target name="instrument" depends="build-dev" description="Instrument the Application Source classes">
<mkdir dir="${instrument.classes.dir}"/>
<!-- Create the coverage directory if it does not exist -->
<mkdir dir="${coverage.dir}"/>

<echo>Instrumenting application classes under 'artemispm' package ...</echo>
<!-- Instrument only the class files in artemispm.* package,
     and place the instrumented classes in ${instrument.classes.dir} directory -->
<emma enabled="${emma.enabled}">
  <instr instrpathref="instrument.classpath"
         destdir="${instrument.classes.dir}"
         metadatafile="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma"
         mode="copy" merge="true">
    <filter includes="artemispm.*"/>
  </instr>
</emma>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Ant are you running?  We just migrated from 1.7.x to 1.9.2 and had to fix some errors that popped up in 1.9. I think part of it was properties that were defined elsewhere had to be pre-defined now ahead of time.   We also have multiple build files and generally everything works if you run from the top-level build.xml because the other files get executed/called from the top-level.  Almost sound like you might be in a lower level build file, which has not imported other targets, including the build-dev target.

Comment: Why the separate files?  It may be worth looking into consolidating. I would do that first.  If you want to fix the issue, can you expand on your snippet, are build-dev and build-test both included in build.xml? or does one include the other?

Comment: If you invoke build.xml (running ant without `-f` parameter) then both build-test and build-dev should be imported into build.xml; if you run `ant -f build-test.xml xxx` then build-dev should be imported into build-test.